# Ship a ROS package with Docker

Tags: ros, docker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I have a ROS package which has been well-tested with Caffe and Tensorflow + Cuda.
It is quite a burden explaining to users how to use this package and I feel it is best to ship it to users as a docker image. Now, on the docker hub, I see osrf/ros images for example, indigo as well as gazebo (which btw are dependencies for this project).

I have created the [dockerfile](https://github.com/lakehanne/gps/blob/master/Dockerfile) as well as built the [docker image](https://cloud.docker.com/swarm/lakehanne/repository/docker/lakehanne/gps/general) but I find that the ros environment within the docker build is not active. I cannot `catkin_init_workspace`, `catkin build` nor `catkin make`. For the record, I pulled the [OSRF/ros_indigo](https://github.com/osrf/docker_images/blob/d9efe4367b9d376fd97a154bdaba896ca0382645/ros/indigo/indigo-ros-base/Dockerfile) image in building my ros environment.  There is no ros installation path in `/opt/ros/...` either.

The instructions are scarce and I wonder what I may be doing wrong.

Would appreciate your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259667/ship-a-ros-package-with-docker/) by [lakehanne](https://answers.ros.org/users/22838/lakehanne/) on ROS Answers with karma: 152 on 2017-04-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you are making a mistake in your Dockerfile. You cannot layer docker images the way you have tried.

I believe that when you have:

```
FROM ros:indigo-ros-core
LABEL maintainer "patlekano@gmail.com"

# install ros packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    ros-indigo-ros-base=1.1.4-0* \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install gazebo
FROM gazebo:gzserver6

FROM ubuntu:trusty
```

The image will actually only use `ubuntu:trusy` and 'forget' about the things you did before. You are probably best of starting from the image that has most of what you want, and then install the rest on top of it (using apt) it's a bit of a hassle, but I recently created a CUDA enabled trusty-ros-indigo-moveit image this way and it worked fine. I have removed a couple of things so not entirely certain but I think it should work like this. The entrypoint is the same as the one from [indigo-ros-core](https://github.com/osrf/docker_images/tree/d9efe4367b9d376fd97a154bdaba896ca0382645/ros/indigo/indigo-ros-core).

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:8.0-devel-ubuntu14.04
# setup environment
RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8

# setup sources.list
RUN echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu trusty main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list

# install bootstrap tools
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
    python-rosdep \
    python-rosinstall \
    python-vcstools \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# bootstrap rosdep
RUN rosdep init \
    && rosdep update

# install ros packages
ENV ROS_DISTRO indigo
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    ros-indigo-desktop-full=1.1.4-0* \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# setup entrypoint
COPY ./ros_entrypoint.sh /

ENTRYPOINT ["/ros_entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["bash"]

# ros-indigo-ros-base
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    ros-indigo-ros-base=1.1.4-0* \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# moveit-indigo-ci
ENV TERM xterm

# Setup catkin workspace
ENV CATKIN_WS=/root/ws_moveit
RUN mkdir -p $CATKIN_WS/src
WORKDIR $CATKIN_WS/src

# Commands are combined in single RUN statement with "apt/lists" folder removal to reduce image size
RUN wstool init . && \
    # Download moveit source so that we can get necessary dependencies
    wstool merge https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros-planning/moveit/${ROS_DISTRO}-devel/moveit.rosinstall && \
    wstool update && \
    # Update apt-get because previous images clear this cache
    apt-get -qq update && \
    # Install some base dependencies
    apt-get -qq install -y \
        # Required for rosdep command
        sudo \
        # Required for installing dependencies
        python-rosdep \
        # Preferred build tool
        python-catkin-tools \
        # Not sure if necessary:
        ros-$ROS_DISTRO-rosbash \
        ros-$ROS_DISTRO-rospack && \
    # Download all dependencies of MoveIt!
    rosdep update && \
    rosdep install -y --from-paths . --ignore-src --rosdistro ${ROS_DISTRO} --as-root=apt:false && \
    # Remove the source code from this container. TODO: in the future we may want to keep this here for further optimization of later containers
    cd .. && \
    rm -rf src/ && \
    # Clear apt-cache to reduce image size
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Continous Integration Setting
ENV IN_DOCKER 1

# moveit-indigo-release
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        ros-${ROS_DISTRO}-moveit-* && \
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2017-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lakehanne](https://answers.ros.org/users/22838/lakehanne/) on 2017-04-23**:
Thanks. I will try this. Where is this Dockerfile domiciled? I need to find the file `ros_entrypoint.sh`. Thanks

**Comment by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) on 2017-04-24**:
It's an extract of a bigger Dockerfile so I haven't tested this exact file and it's online. The entrypoint can be found [here.](https://github.com/osrf/docker_images/tree/d9efe4367b9d376fd97a154bdaba896ca0382645/ros/indigo/indigo-ros-core) good luck.

**Comment by [lakehanne](https://answers.ros.org/users/22838/lakehanne/) on 2017-04-25**:
Thanks. May I ask why you installed ros-indigo from source and also pulled `ros-indigo-ros-base=1.1.4-0*` in the same dockerfile? I just finished building my  `caffe` image with your `nvidia/cuda:8.0-devel-ubuntu14.04`, `ros-indigo-full` and `ros-indigo-base` and I found that my build is about 3GB.

**Comment by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) on 2017-04-28**:
He, looks like I have some duplicate parts in there :) Pretty sure that's an error. I copied most from Dockerfiles from osrf and MoveIt! and didn't carefully inspect everything, so that's probably how it got in there. The image does get quite large but at least in my case it couldn't be helped.

**Comment by [lakehanne](https://answers.ros.org/users/22838/lakehanne/) on 2017-04-28**:
Okay. Thanks for the clarification. I have cleaned it up and my dockerfile is [here](https://github.com/lakehanne/gps/blob/master/Dockerfile). Thank you!

**Comment by [lakehanne](https://answers.ros.org/users/22838/lakehanne/) on 2017-04-28**:
BTW, how did you compile your `cuda-8.0`? From  `.deb` or via the `.run` file? I couldn't get my image to populate a `matplotlib` window as I wanted when I run the docker image with `DISPLAY` support.

**Comment by [lakehanne](https://answers.ros.org/users/22838/lakehanne/) on 2017-04-29**:
I have removed the second `ros-indigo-base` install file and it's lesser in bytes. Thanks for your help though.